# Launch an app on device boot-up in iOS - Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

After some googling around, I did not find any useful tutorials of how to implement the functionality of launching an app in iOS on device bootup. The aim is to start an app upon device bootup, and the app should be running in background.

Can someone please advise on how can I achieve this in Xamarin.iOS using C#-based code?

Comment: Is your app a VoIP app?

Comment: No. An app that does a detection and send data over a web service.

Comment: Detects what? I think Bluetooth state restoration can restart your app, otherwise the user needs to do it.

Comment: @Paulw11 : The app does a detection of bluetooth tags. It gathers the ID and sends same over a remote web service. 

The app currently needs to be started manually. Now I want the app to startup on device boot without user's intervention.

Comment: You need to opt in to Core Bluetooth state restoration; I am not sure how to do it in C#, but it is described in the Core Bluetooth programming guide and it should be much the same as in Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: What do you mean by this `Core Bluetooth state restoration` ?

Comment: Google for the Core Bluetooth Programming guide. It is described in there. You have to set a property on your CBCentralManager and maintain an active service search. iOS will then relaunch your app when a service you are searching for is discovered.

Comment: Hmm I see. There is the class of CBCentralManager in Xamarin.iOS. 

Do you have an idea on how this can achieved in C#?

Comment: The properties and settings should be much the same. I have never used Xamarin but it should be pretty straight forward if you follow Apple’s guide.

Comment: Hmm do you have an example on how to implement in iOS ?

Comment: Here is a Swift example that uses state restoration https://github.com/paulw11/BTMonitor/blob/master/BTMonitor/BTManager.swift